# How do you solve $\lim_{n\to \infty}{n[(1+\frac{c}{n})^{n}-(1-\frac{c}{n})^{-n}]}$ without L’Hopital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know that solution is: $-c^2e^c$

$$\lim\nolimits_{n\to \infty}{n\left[\left(1+\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n}-\left(1-\frac{c}{n}\right)^{-n}\right]}$$

Hint: common factor to $\left(1+\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n}$ and then to use approaches

Comment: Can you include some information in your post regarding your own thoughts on the problem, and ideally, include your own workings on the limit, and where, specifically you get stuck?

Comment: Hint: common factor to $\left(1+\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n}$ and then to use approaches

Answer (score 3):

As a big hint, assuming WLOG that $c > 0$, we have as $n \to \infty$

$$\left(1+\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n}\uparrow e^c  \downarrow\left(1-\frac{c}{n}\right)^{-n},$$

and for all $n > c$

$$0 \leqslant n\left[\left(1-\frac{c}{n}\right)^{-n}-\left(1+\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n}\right] = n\left(1-\frac{c}{n}\right)^{-n}\left[1 -  \left(1-\frac{c^2}{n^2}\right)^{n}\right] \leqslant \ldots$$

See if you can finish by first applying Bernoulli's inequality to the last term on the RHS and then applying the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $e^x = \lim_{n\to+\infty} \left[1+\frac{x}{n}\right]^n$

Comment: ... although the limit is of the form $\infty \cdot (\infty - \infty)$, so there is a *nontrivial* insight needed here above and beyond simply recognizing the relation to the exponential.

Answer (score -1):

$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left[ n\left( 1 + \frac{c}{n} \right)^n - n\left( 1 - \frac{c}{n} \right)^{-n}\right] = 
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left[ (n + c)\left( 1 + \frac{c}{n} \right)^{n-1} - (n - c)\left( 1 - \frac{c}{n} \right)^{-n - 1}\right] = \\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left[ (n + c)\underbrace{\left( 1 + \frac{c}{n} \right)^{-1}}_{1}\underbrace{\left( 1 + \frac{c}{n} \right)^{n}}_{e^c} - (n - c)\underbrace{\left( 1 - \frac{c}{n} \right)^{-1}}_{1}\underbrace{\left( 1 - \frac{c}{n} \right)^{-n}}_{e^c}\right] = 2\cdot c \cdot e^c\\
$$

Comment: Your last step as well as final answer is wrong. - 1